# Local notifications queue ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

Just a simple question, do local notifications join a queue, if they are fired while they're in app?

Comment: Are you scheduling them, or firing them immediately within the app?

Comment: @paulbailey, I'm basically wanting to schedule some, but then for example if they're in the app and the event triggers, i don't want them to get the notification when they quit.

Comment: AS @Sulthan has said, if the app is running, a notification firing will immediately call `[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean.

Local notifications are handled sequentially according to their fire date.

And from the documentation:

> An application can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the system keeps the soonest firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest.

Comment: If I'm in app, and the notification fires, I'm wondering if it will wait until I quit before displaying or if it fires without any visual output?

Comment: The notification usually asks the user if he wants to start the app. When the app is already started and active, `[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:]` is called.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they do and in a FIFO manner. You can go through the NSNotificationQueue

Comment: I believe that you're confusing `UILocalNotification` and `NSNotification`.